# excel vba scatterplot not plotting x values but sequence

Tags: excel, vba, plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a few scattercharts that will tell how close a measurement is to a prediction. On the X axis we will have the predicted value and on the y axis we will have the measured value. When the two are the same the datapoint lies an a red line which has the same x as y value. In this way we can say whether our predictions are good, or maybe too conservative. Below is an example of 4 datapoints.

```
Measured  predicted
12        10    
15        14
16        17
18        18
```

Instead of plotting the points at (12, 10) (15, 14) etc... it plots the points at (1, 10) (2, 14) (3, 16) and (4, 18). So on the x value it's actually plotting the rownumber and not the value.
Im using a rather large VBA script to accomplish this because the user has a lot of options when choosing which data to plot. When I rightclick the graph and click 'select data' and then check the selected ranges they do match with the ranges of values I'd like to plot. Both datasets are stored in different worksheets.

I've already found some solutions that had to do with numbers saved as text, the nature of the x axis and inconsistensies in the datasets however none of those worked for me.

these are some of the relevant variables. The worksheets ws1, ws2, ws3 and wspred are declared earlier with `set ws1 = thisworkbook.worksheets("blad1")`
the measured data is stored in one of 20 worksheets which are referred to with the variable sourcename. The predicted data is stored in wspred.

```
'date processing
Dim DateStart As String
Dim Dateend As String
Dim rngstart As Range
Dim rngend As Range
'listboxprocessing
Dim plotvar As String
Dim SourceSig As String
Dim SourceLength As Long
Dim SourceName As String
Dim SignalLength As Long
Dim SignalName As String
Dim SignalRange As Range
Dim predSignalName As String
'dataselection for blad 3 & 4
Dim predRange As Range
Dim MesRange As Range
Dim predcol As Long
Dim MesCol As Long
Dim predStart As Long
Dim predEnd As Long
Dim MesStart As Long
Dim MesEnd As Long
```

This is the code concerning the graphs

```
 If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
ws3.Activate
ws3.Shapes.AddChart
ws3.ChartObjects.Delete
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad3").ComboBox1.Clear
ws1.Activate
'create red reference line
ws3.Cells(1, 1).Value = "red" & " " & "line"
ws3.Cells(2, 1).Value = 0
ws3.Cells(3, 1).Value = 10

'matching measured data with selected predicted data
For i = 0 To ListBox23.ListCount - 1
    plotvar = ListBox23.List(i)
    SourceSig = Mid(ListBox23.List(i), 13)
    SignalLength = InStr(plotvar, "-->") + 3
    SignalName = Mid(plotvar, SignalLength)
    predSignalName = Mid(plotvar, SignalLength)
    If Left(SourceSig, 5) = "a thing" Then
        SourceName = Left(SourceSig, 7)
        SignalName = Mid(SignalName, 10, 4)
        ElseIf Left(SourceSig, 9) = "something" Then
            SourceName = Left(SourceSig, 13)
            SignalName = Mid(SignalName, 16, 4)
        ElseIf Left(SourceSig, 7) = "something else" Then
            SourceName = Left(SourceSig, 10)
            SignalName = Mid(SignalName, 13, 4)
        Else: SourceName = "something different"
    End If
    'creating range from Predictions
    wspred.Activate
    If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        DateStart = TextboxMonth1 & "/" & textboxDate1 & "/" & TextboxYear1 
        Dateend = TextboxMonth2 & "/" & TextboxDate2 & "/" & TextboxYear2 
        On Error Resume Next
        predStart = wspred.Columns("b").find(DateStart).Row
        If predStart = 0 Then
            MsgBox "selected date not found"
            predStart = 2
        Else: predEnd = wspred.Columns("b").find(what:=Dateend, after:=Cells(1, 2), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            If predEnd = 0 Then
                MsgBox "selected date not found"
                predEnd = wspred.Cells(wspred.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = False Then
        predStart = 1
        predEnd = wspred.Cells(wspred.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    predcol = wspred.rows(1).find(predSignalName).Column
    Set predRange = wspred.Range(Cells(predStart, predcol), Cells(predEnd, predcol))
    'creating range from source
    Worksheets(SourceName).Activate
    If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        DateStart = TextboxMonth1 & "/" & textboxDate1 & "/" & TextboxYear1 
        Dateend = TextboxMonth2 & "/" & TextboxDate2 & "/" & TextboxYear2 
        On Error Resume Next
        MesStart = Worksheets(SourceName).Columns("b").find(DateStart).Row
        If MesStart = 0 Then
            MsgBox "selected date not found"
        Else: MesEnd = Worksheets(SourceName).Columns("b").find(what:=Dateend, after:=Cells(1, 2), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            If MesEnd = 0 Then
                MsgBox "selected date not found"
                MesEnd = Worksheets(SourceName).Cells(Worksheets(SourceName).rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = False Then
        MesStart = 1
        MesEnd = Worksheets(SourceName).Cells(Worksheets(SourceName).rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    MesCol = Worksheets(SourceName).rows(1).find(SignalName).Column
    Set MesRange = Worksheets(SourceName).Range(Cells(MesStart, MesCol), Cells(MesEnd, MesCol))

        'makes red line
    ws3.Activate
    'ws3.ChartObjects.Delete

        j = i + 1
        m = 3 * j
        ws3.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter, (j - 1) * 300, 0, 300, 300).Select
        With ActiveChart
            .HasLegend = False
            .Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Caption = Worksheets(SourceName).Cells(1, MesCol)
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption = wspred.Cells(1, predcol)
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 5
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 5
        End With

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
            .Name = ""
            .XValues = ws3.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 1))
            .Values = ws3.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 1))
            .MarkerSize = 2
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDot
            .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Format.Line.Transparency = 0
        End With
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
            .Name = "predicted/measured"
            .XValues = predRange.Value
            .Values = MesRange
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStylePlus
            .MarkerSize = 2
            .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(85, 143, 213)
            .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End With

        thisworkbook.worksheets("blad3").ComboBox1.AddItem Mid(ActiveChart.Name, 7, 11)
Next i
End If
```

Edit: I cleaned the code so it uses variables as reference to worksheets. The problem of the x axis showing numbers instead of the actual values still exists. There is another curious error as well. Twice I refer to `thisworkbook.worksheets("blad3").combobox1`, this works. When i use `ws3.combobox1` instead vba returns a 'compile error: method or data member not found' even though `ws3 = thisworkbook.worksheets("blad3").

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried to understand the logic of the code (yet), but I can see many potential bugs:

---

In the code below which is used twice, the `Cells(1, 2)` does not have the worksheet in front of it.  eg in this case  `Worksheets(SourceName).Cells(1, 2)`

```
MesEnd = Worksheets(SourceName).Columns("b").find(what:=Dateend, after:=Cells(1, 2), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

---

Similarly in the code below which .  AND also which worksheet is number 5.
Use `Worksheets("Predictions")` if this is what you mean.

```
Set PredRange = Worksheets(5).Range(Cells(PredStart, Predcol), Cells(PredEnd, Predcol))
```

---

Also here:

```
Set MesRange = Worksheets(SourceName).Range(Cells(MesStart, MesCol), Cells(MesEnd, MesCol))
```

---

Also

```
.XValues = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 1))
.Values = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 1))
```

### ----------------------------------

You should consider using with statements (which also nest) not the full stops.
eg

```
With Worksheets(SourceName)
    Set MesRange = .Range(.Cells(MesStart, MesCol), .Cells(MesEnd, MesCol))
End with
```

### ----------------------------------

You might use an object variable to store the reference to you worksheet

```
eg
Dim wsPred as Worksheeet
Set  wsPred  = Worksheets("Predictions")
```

then in later code you can use `wsPred` instead of `Worksheets("Predictions")`

Harvey

Comment: Admittetly, the code isn't clean. I often rely on a sheet being active so my references can be shorter but using variables is of course better. I'll work on that. With `MesEnd = Worksheets(SourceName).Columns("b").find(what:=Dateend, after:=Cells(1, 2), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row1` is it really necesary to add the worksheets before `Cells(1, 2)`? because you already specified that you want to search within `worksheets(sourcename)`. Also in `worksheets(sourcename)`, sourcename is a variable so i dont know if it's safe to declare a variable for this. After cleaning, code stil didn't work.

Comment: Now that i cleaned the code. It breaks on the line `ws3.ComboBox1.Clear`, When i change this back to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad3").ComboBox1.Clear` it works again. I did set ws3 earlier by `Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad3")`

Comment: Yes cells refers to the active sheet!    It is safe: "sourcename is a variable so I don't know if it's safe to declare a variable for this."     When you say it Breaks" what error message is given?  You need to give more information.  Just saying "it doesn;t work" won't help.  Repost you new "cleaned" code and use the debugger to step through and examine to find where and why it is failing.

Comment: Forgive me for not being clear. Im relatively new to programming and english is not my native language. Depending on a listboxselection the variable 'sourcename' can be the name of one of 20 sheets. If i declare a variable `wssrc` for `thisworkbook.worksheets(sourcename)` will the code still recognize which sheet is referenced to? Also I will update the code in the question.

Comment: wssrc will be set to the worksheet with the name given in the brackets, either whne the name is given explicitly (eg "MyWorksheet") or using a variable.